# Stopping object from being added to array of objects if it already exists

Tags: jquery, arrays

Trying to push object to array only if it does not already exist.

The html includes data attributes to pass id and name (Twig) to jQuery.

```
<a
    data-id="{{ franchise.franchise_id }}"
    data-name="{{ franchise.franchise_name }}"
    class="btn btn-buy btn-block add-to-list">
    Add to List
</a>
```

I am using a click event (.add-to-list) to collect data (id & name) and add it to an array (franchises) to display as a list in the view template.

Here's the jQuery:

```
// initialize array and object variables
let franchises = [];
let franchise = {};

// add to list
$(".add-to-list").on('click', function() {

    // store franchise data in variables
    let id = $(this).data("id");
    let name = $(this).data("name");

    // add values to franchise object
    franchise = {
        'id': id,
        'name': name
    };

    // add object to array if first choice
    if (franchises.length === 0) {
        // alert("franchises array is empty");
        franchises.push({ franchise });
        franchise = {};
    } else {
        // loop thru array as index & obj; loop thru obj as key & value
        // to check if franchise name being added already exists in array
        $.each(franchises, (index, obj) => {
            $.each(obj, (key, value) => {
                // console.log('franchise.name: ' + franchise.name);
                // console.log('value.name: ' + value.name);
                // console.log('key: ' + key);
                if (value.name === franchise.name) {
                    // alert("Franchise already selected");
                    franchise = {};
                    return false;
                } else if (value.name != franchise.name) {
                    franchises.push({franchise});
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // empty franchise obj
    franchise = {};

    // display hidden html
    $("#franchise-selections").css('display', 'block');

    // empty content to display only current elements in franchises[]
    $("#choices").empty();

    // loop thru array as index & obj; then loop thru obj as key & value
    $.each(franchises, (index, obj) => {
        $.each(obj, (key, value) => {
            $("#choices").append('<a class="list-group-item" id='+key.id+'> ' + value.name + '<span class="pull-right">&times;</span></a>');
        });
    });

});
```

When I add an item already in the array, the console.log shows that the values match, and the alert verifies that a match was found, but the object is added to the array regardless. This has me stumped.

I cannot figure out what's wrong with the code that it proceeds to add the item to the array.

Any help to find my errors is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why curly braces for franchise during push. No need for curly braces.

Comment: Why two for loops? No need for the 'inner' for loop, as you are going to compare one or two properties specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you will be pushing the same object again and again in several iterations of the loop:

```
franchises.push({franchise});
```

You can only decide whether it should be added *after* the loop, as only then you are sure it does not occur in the array yet.

I leave it to you to fix that, but I would like to suggest a much easier way to keep the list unique: use an object keyed by name instead of an array:

```
const franchises = {}; // Not array

$(".add-to-list").on('click', function() {
    // Add values to franchise object
    // If already existing, then this just replaces previous id:
    franchises[$(this).data("name")] = $(this).data("id");
    $("#franchise-selections").css('display', 'block');
    // Empty choices, and populate again by mapping the object to HTML elements
    $("#choices").empty().append(
        $.map(franchises, function(id, name) {
            return $('<a>').addClass("list-group-item").attr('id', id).text(name).append(
                $('<span>').addClass("pull-right").html('&times')
            );
        })
    );
});
```

Now you don't have to iterate anything to find whether you already have the name in your list. You can simply assign it. If it was already there, it will just get replaced.

I have also updated a bit the loop where you display the list, making it more jQuery-like.

If you need the items in reversed order (most recently inserted at the top*), then chain a `reverse()` call after `map(...)`, so that the last three lines become:

```
        }).reverse()
    );
});
```

(*) All popular browsers provide the properties of objects in order of insertion when they are not just digits. If they are digits they are ordered numerically instead. But unless you have such names, that will not be the case for you.

Comment: That is beautiful code! Thanks so much for taking the time to look at my challenge. I like your elimination of the loop. I like the franchises object versus array. I am unfamiliar with how map() works or the return. Why is $(this).data("id") set equal to $(this).data("name") and why is the latter in square brackets? I have to study this closely to try to figure out how it works.

Comment: The square brackets create a property. So in general `a['b'] = 1` will create a property in object `a` with the name `b` and with value 1. If `a` was `{}` it will become `{ b: 1 }` after that. Does that help to explain your last question? `map` can do wonders: it is like `each`, but it returns an array of all the values that were returned by the callback function. And as `append` can deal with such arrays, it is an ideal solution here.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly `$(this).data("name")` makes `name` a property of the object `franchises`  and its assigned value becomes `$(this).data("id")`. Sort of like franchises.name = id. Not sure I have that right. The code's brevity is amazing, however, sometimes the brevity precludes the understanding available in lengthier versions that scream "refactor me!" Toward the end when you use `id` and `name`, I thought,  where are these variables defined? I also don't see `push()` because I want to use `unshift()` so the new item goes on top.

Comment: Indeed it is like `franchises[name] = id`. In practice object properties are iterated in order of insertion (except when they are only digits). If you want them in reverse, you can just chain `.reverse()` to the result of the `map` method: it is a plain JavaScript method available on arrays.

Comment: Your work inspires me. Thanks for the dialog. Chaining `reverse()` works fine. One question: how is `id` made a property of `franchises`?

Comment: `id` becomes a property value in the assignment `franchises[$(this).data("name")] = $(this).data("id");`. Maybe you prefer to write that in multiple statements: `const name = $(this).data("name"), id = $(this).data("id");` and then `franchises[name] = id;`. Note that the other occurrences of `id` and `name` are other variables (callback function parameters), but with the same sense: they are also the property names and values of the franchises object (which in general will have multiple properties, each with a value).

Comment: The longer way helps me see better what's happening. I think shortcuts are best after a thorough understanding of all that the shortcut eliminates. I still don't understand `franchises[name] = id`. Seems like it should be `franchises[id]  = id`. I just discovered that using `splice()` on `franchises` throws a TypeError that `splice` is not a function of `franchises`. I suppose that's because `franchises` is not an array.

Comment: Indeed, it is not an array. Where the properties of an array are numeric (indexes), the properties of a generic object are strings. The whole idea of `franchises[name]` is that you then ensure you cannot have two different entries with the same name, which seemed to be your aim. It is like you have one slot for each name. If it does not exist yet, it is created. But if it already exists, the value (`id` in your case) assigned to it ends up in the *same* slot, overwriting what was already there. That way you avoid the whole lookup thing.

Comment: Note that you can convert the object to an array temporarily, if you want to apply array functions to it. `Object.values(franchises)` will give you an array of all `id`s, while  `Object.keys(franchises)` will give an array of all names. And if you want both as an array of pairs, then use `Object.entries(franchises)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's  the jQuery that appears to resolve the problem above.

```
// create array to hold franchise list
let franchises = [];

// add to list
$(".add-to-list").on('click', function() {

    // store franchise data in variables
    let id = $(this).data("id");
    let name = $(this).data("name");

    // add object to empty array (first selection)
    if (franchises.length === 0) {
        franchises.unshift({ 'id': id, 'name': name  });
    } else if (franchises.length > 0) {
        // loop thru array as index & obj to check if new name already in array
        $.each(franchises, (index, obj) => {
            if (obj.name === name) {
                alert("Franchise already selected");
            } else if (obj.name != name) {
                franchises.unshift({ 'id': id, 'name': name  });
            }
        });
    }

    // empty html content to display only current elements in franchises[]
    $("#choices").empty();

    // loop thru array as index & obj
    $.each(franchises, (index, obj) => {
        $("#choices").append('<a class="list-group-item" id='+obj.id+'> ' + obj.name + '<span class="pull-right">&times;</span></a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you believe your answer is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be _deleted_ instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it an answer.

Comment: I didn't vandalize my post. Poor choice of words. I wanted to delete it, except it appeared that in doing so the excellent answer from trincot would also have been deleted. Instead I elected to edit it. What value is the wrong answer? You must have a lot of free time.

Comment: You can delete this answer without deleting the question. You DID vandalize the post, because you removed any information that _made it an answer_. I'm just following site guidelines, there is no need for you to try to insult me, it will get neither of is anywhere. What value is an "answer" that says "look at the other answer"?

Comment: I'm unsure what authority you have, but you charged me with vandalism in your first six words. And now with insulting you. You might consider reflecting on the presumptions that underlie your action and attitude before writing to someone you don't know and calling them a vandal. Do the site guidelines say anything about extending courtesy? You owe me an apology for charging me with vandalism because I edited my post out of respect for trincot's superior code that made mine superfluous. It is the presence of his solution for the community that precludes me from deleting the post.

Comment: While I don't have much authority here, as this website is largely self-moderated, my comments to you have been out of courtesy to follow the sites rules and have not been a personal attack on you. I've done my best to explain to you the improper thing you did, told you the proper way to do it, and told you _why_. I'm sorry you feel offended, that wasn't the goal.